# Validating HTML form details before submitting it - using php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I had an upload form on my website, where users entered details about their upload file, selected the file and uploaded to the webserver.

The POST action of the form was to submit the file to a php page called upload_control.php, where the post details were validated, and if correct the file was stored on disk an entry was placed in the database. The file was renamed to ID_name before storing, where the ID was taken from the database, as the largest ID so far (just a counter).

Now things have changed and it makes more sense to upload the file to storage elsewhere. This is done straight by the user, the action of the form points to the other server which stores the file if the form was submitted correctly. [ I have no control over the processing done by the other server, it's a storage solution like amazon s3 ]

The problem is: How do I get the last used ID from my database, so that I rename the file to ID_filename with javascript before uploading? (I can store the filename on a hidden form field and the remote server will understand to rename it when it receives it).

Better yet: Is there a way to validate all the form details - using php. not javascript,  before submiting the form to the storage solution?

My thoughts are towards sending the form details to a php script on my server with ajax, upon hitting the submit button but before posting, so that the php script can get the latest id from the database, validate the request, send back the new details or the new id, and then really submit the form. -- But how can this by done?

Comment: If you use AJAX, you will always have the problem that the user is able to manipulate the POST data and inject files with wrong IDs to your S3 store. Which means, your S3 storage can be used as a free file-hosting service. I think you should consider a more appropriate way to fully stay in control what's uploaded and under which name.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are leaning toward not using Javascript for the client-side portion of the validation?  Regardless of how you implement the pre-submission validation, you will most certainly have to perform server-side validation as well to ensure the user has not maliciously manipulated the data.

Comment: @hakre: The post request a user sends to S3 contains a policy file and a hmach sha1 signature of that policy. If I generate the filename in php, I can create a policy matching the filename on runtime, so only files matching the exact filename would be accepted.

Comment: @Mattygabe: As I said above, php would be better so that I can also generate a good policy matching file. As for the ID getting part, I don't know how to get that with javascript - I have to get it from the database before uploading. But if I do it with php before serving the upload page, I risk inconsistency of the IDs if two users try to upload at the same time. They would get the same 'last ID' from the db.

Comment: @george_mt Assuming you need to use PHP for the validation, why can't you use a local AJAX call to your PHP function for validation, passing all of that data, and updating the client side with error information, or submitting the data upon success to a different PHP function.  That function would then generate the good policy matching file, and grab the latest ID all moments before sending the information to S3?

Comment: @george_mt: So the user actually uploads the file to your host first? Or are you giving away the policy for a direct submission from the users browser on to amazon s3?

Comment: @haker: The second - the user posts the form to amazon, but together he posts the policy string and the signature to the string. The policy can have fields to validate the filename that can be empty (so no validation - what I do now) but I can also populate them with the desired filename (hopefully with this ajax-php mechanism) so that the check will not be correct if he uploads with wrong filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on button click call php function through ajax, and pass all the data collected from page to service as json, php is very strong at parsing json. and you can return result from that method to indicate whether to data is authenticated or not. A nice tutorial to hook you up is this.

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp